# Meteor email ETIMEOUT error

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I am trying to use the email package but I keep getting the error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
I20150418-09:24:22.233(-4)?     at Object.Future.wait (/Users/tinzors/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
I20150418-09:24:22.233(-4)?     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:76:1)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:153:1)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendEmail (app/server/methods/email.js:10:11)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     - - - - -
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
I20150418-09:24:22.234(-4)?     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

Here is my click event that calls the email method:

```
click .saveUserDetails': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();


    'click .saveUserDetails': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
               'demoemail@gmail.com',
               'demoemail@gmail.com',
               'Hello from Meteor!',
               'user confirmed!');
}
```

Here is my email environment setup:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://demoemail@gmail.com:stackoverflowpw@smtp.gmail.com:25/';
});
```

And here is my email method:

```
Meteor.methods({
 sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
 check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

this.unblock();

Email.send({
  to: to,
  from: from,
  subject: subject,
  text: text
});
```

} 
});

Anyone have any idea what might be going on? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hosting provider/ISP may be blocking SMTP/Port 25.

This is quite common as a method to prevent servers/users being used for sending spam. Try using an alternative port or get in touch with your hosting provider/ISP to remove the restriction.

Comment: I see, which other ports would you recommend? Is there any restriction on the port # i can use?

Comment: @user1547174 There isn't anything I can particularly recommend. It depends on what your email provider offers. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en. Google Apps offers 25, 465 & 557. Gmail requires TLS/SSL to use those ports. There are also purpose built providers such as mandrill which can do this. The best thing would be to get your ISP to remove the block in my opinion.